# How to render UIImage async?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I need to draw image async, but [UIImageView setImage:someImage] is not thread safe. So I have to implement a thread safe draw function by myself.

Is it possible in iOS? And how? I know how to use Quartz do custom drawing.

Special thanks!

Comment: please visit my answer asynchronous image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947523/asyncronous-image-loading-in-uitableview-cell/12947646#12947646

Comment: but SDWebImage render image in main thread

Comment: All interface changes must be done in Main Thread. Performing interface changes on the background thread will not update the interface. SDWebImage is an asynchronous image downloading and caching library, isn't that what you want, async UIImage like your title suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `drawsAsynchronously` property of `CALayer` and implement your own imageView/imageLayer. This may help to improve the responsiveness of your GUI.

Comment: how if i should make it compatible with iOS5, drawsAsynchronously implemented in iOS6

Comment: Maybe you could use a CATiledLayer to do asynchronous drawing < iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you just need to load the images in the background. And then draw them on the foreground thread. Have a look here
[loading images from a background thread using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502073/loading-images-from-a-background-thread-using-blocks/7502281#7502281)

Comment: i want to draw them in background to make their container scroll view more smooth

Comment: Could you tell more about the context of what you are trying to achieve ? I'm still thinking, loading in background might be what you want ...

Comment: UIImage already loaded from local file and resized small using QuartzCore in background thread. Now I want to render UIImage in memory to screen in background.